# InstrumentationScope in opentelemetry

Tags: open-telemetry

[Here](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-proto/blob/ce4475566d50cf2b2dd377953e2cddab8ff59117/opentelemetry/proto/trace/v1/trace.proto#L64), ScopeSpans is defined. Comment says:

> // A collection of Spans produced by an InstrumentationScope.

It also has a attribute 'InstrumentationScope'.

So is there a connection between comment and this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the comment describes the design of the object: All spans in the object are produced by the same instrumentation scope - which is the described by the `scope` field.